# TLS notificationmail - where to check version and change it?

Tags: azure-web-app-service

I received a mail about TLS requirements for the webapps yesterday.
Just wanted to check which for which apps the TLS version will be changed, but I cannot find it anywhere in the portal.

Is there an easy way to check this in the Azure Portal? Or are there any other ways to check.

This was some text in the mail:
•   By April 30, 2018: 
o   Through the Azure portal and Azure Resource Manager templates, you’ll be able to select the minimum-required TLS version (1.1 or 1.2) for your app.
o   We’ll configure App Service apps to require only newer TLS versions (1.1 and 1.2)—two months before the required date.
•   After June 30, 2018, all newly created App Service apps will be automatically configured to require TLS 1.2. You’ll still retain the option to configure earlier TLS versions for your apps, if necessary, for compatibility with older browser clients.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have not yet introduced this option for App Service in the Azure Portal. That will be done in a few months and no later than the end of April, 2018. Once introduced, you will be able to select your TLS level from 1.0, moving to 1.1 or 1.2, for each of your apps. From the end of June, 2018, all new Web Apps will be created with 1.2 as a default.

Comment: but when I run security tools it shows me that azure app also available TLS 1.0,1.1, so i need to disable the older version , how could I do that ? via az command or any front end?

Answer (score 3):

As of 2018-04-30 you can modify your old site to only serve **TLS 1.2** and up by going to your app service, then SSL settings, then setting your minimum TLS Version. Alternatively, if you have created a new site which has defaulted TLS 1.2 and you want to change it to support **TLS 1.0**, you can go to the same setting and set it as appropriate.

[image: azure portal ssl settings]

Comment: but when I run security tools it shows me that azure app also available TLS 1.0,1.1, so i need to disable the older version , how could I do that ? via az command or any front end

Comment: @SaadAwan the minimum works as expected for me (security tools shows 1.0 and 1.1 as unavailabe/unsupported). You do have to restart the app service for it to take effect though.

Comment: I already restarted the app after selecting the TLS 1.2, and run tool which shows me 1.0,1.2 is still available. keep in mind that I have used custom domain from cloudflare. may be TLS are coming from there end?

Comment: @SaadAwan yeah, if you're using cloudflare domain and are using it as a reverse proxy, then that would make sense, the 1.2 restriction probably needs to happen at cloudflare. use your security tool to inspect [your_site].azurewebsites.net and I'm pretty sure it'll show as only offering 1.2.