# TLS notificationmail from microsoft - can I still select TLS 1.0 after June 30 2018

Tags: azure, tls1.2

It is not clear in the TLS notification email from Microsoft, if I actually can select TLS 1.0 after June 30th 2018 in Azure web apps.

I understand that new web apps by default will run TLS 1.2, GREAT!
but can I select between TLS 1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 on Azure web apps after June 30th
... so all of our .net framework client still can connect to older solutions running in azure web app

This is the email from Microsoft:

- By April 30, 2018: 
  Through the Azure portal and Azure Resource Manager templates, you’ll be able to select the minimum-required TLS version (1.1 or 1.2) for your app.

We’ll configure App Service apps to require only newer TLS versions (1.1 and 1.2)—two months before the required date.

- After June 30, 2018, all newly created App Service apps will be automatically configured to require TLS 1.2. You’ll still retain the option to configure earlier TLS versions for your apps, if necessary, for compatibility with older browser clients.

Comment: the phrasing suggets yes (versions), but i dont know exactly

Comment: exactly - I'm glad I'm not the only one that cannot determine based upon their email.

Comment: but you should really drop tls 1.0 so...

Comment: I cannot control what .net framework version my customers are running locally on their machine and still a lot of companies have policies NOT to upgrade to .net 4.5 in 2018. I do not understand. 
If Microsoft could release an update to .net 4 framwork, so this one also support TLS 1.1/1.2, that would be great!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TLS notificationmail - where to check version and change it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171078/tls-notificationmail-where-to-check-version-and-change-it)

Comment: yes, you can set it to still support TLS 1.0. more details here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48171078/tls-notificationmail-where-to-check-version-and-change-it/50118448#50118448